# Block all except whitelisted IPs

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudflare

I would like to block all access to our demo site for some time with the exception of a group of listed IPs & IP ranges. Could you advise on how to do this?

I am hosting on digital ocean and I have cloudflare activated.

Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straightforward to achieve:

1. Ensure that the DNS record for your demo site is [proxied by Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169626-Identifying-subdomains-compatible-with-Cloudflare-s-proxy). You can check this in the Cloudflare Dashboard for your domain, in the DNS tab.
2. [Add a Firewall Rule](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-dashboard/create-edit-delete-rules) that will block all the traffic for your demo site unless it is coming from a list of allowed IP addresses. For example, using an expression such as:

```
(not ip.src in {192.0.2.1 192.0.2.2 192.0.2.3} and http.host eq "demo.example.com")
```

You can also define [an IP List](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-ip-lists/) and reference to it in your Firewall rule - this would make it easier to maintain the list over time in a single place.

You can then turn the rule ON and OFF when needed.

Comment: Following your steps I've been able to set up properly. Thanks very much.